# "DoS attack: Smurf" in router logs - should i worry?

Tags: networking, security, ip

Here is 2 day filtered log from my Netgear 6300 Router. It seems that I am constantly having SMURF attacks.

Based on my router settings it seems that I am being protected. 
I have "Disable Port Scan and DoS Protection" not checked.

Should I be concerned?

```
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [65.94.16.255], Monday, Oct 27,2014 08:00:07
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [5.165.128.255], Monday, Oct 27,2014 04:59:45
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [212.93.114.255], Monday, Oct 27,2014 04:53:51
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [212.93.114.255], Monday, Oct 27,2014 04:39:03
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Monday, Oct 27,2014 01:26:04
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [178.93.190.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 23:03:15
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [79.100.214.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 22:10:32
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [178.122.130.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 21:51:44
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [113.116.37.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 20:45:48
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [176.192.169.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 20:17:49
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [178.40.61.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 20:09:16
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [46.12.205.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 18:19:42
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [2.139.4.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 18:06:55
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [92.84.71.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 17:08:54
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [92.36.199.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 17:08:47
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.163.44.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 16:19:34
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [78.131.51.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 15:55:13
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [88.19.184.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 14:24:54
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [92.49.190.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 14:11:59
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [197.34.59.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 12:17:27
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [94.29.242.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 10:36:32
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [95.42.23.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 09:41:31
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [212.93.114.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 09:36:42
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [94.29.242.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 09:36:41
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [94.29.242.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 09:21:20
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [212.93.114.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 09:21:19
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 08:52:49
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [94.29.242.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 07:35:55
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [124.72.82.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 07:06:37
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [110.195.133.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 07:00:17
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [124.72.82.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 06:20:53
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [117.199.135.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 06:06:39
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [117.63.242.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 05:57:10
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [37.208.139.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 05:18:02
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [91.79.136.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 05:10:37
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 04:38:28
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 03:53:08
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [120.61.210.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 02:34:36
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [120.61.210.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 02:19:34
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 00:36:18
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [176.60.164.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 00:35:26
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [39.44.101.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 00:19:29
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [188.18.11.255], Sunday, Oct 26,2014 00:06:27
```

Comment: Probably. If your router is notifying you like it is intended then I would be a little concerned.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that it is being blocked. Is this a common ocurence that people get these attacks? Why would I be getting it? Does it indicate that my computers might be infected with a virus or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Smurf:

To in small increments take from or give to an entity.

To make methamphetamine, drug cooks have "Smurfs" to buy 2 boxes of advil cold and sinus a day until there is enough.

(distributed)DoS Attack:

To overload a server and bring it down, therefore "D"enying service to anyone connecting to the server for a legitimate purpose.

Someone is very slowly taking all your bandwidth and attempting to crash .. something. Do you run a web server? If not, it is entirely possible that malware is making your computer slowly DoS things as part of a botnet sort of thing.