# First Smurf attacks and now LAN access from remote - What is happening?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Here is the log from my Router.

First I was getting Smurf attacks -- look at ["DoS attack: Smurf" in router logs - should i worry?](https://superuser.com/questions/832758/dos-attack-smurf-in-router-logs-should-i-worry)

and now this.

I see entries in my wireless router logs which might be indicative of some sort of vulnerability or attack that might be occurring. However, I don't know; maybe what I am seeing is commonplace and I shouldn't worry.

Therefore I am asking for help in interpreting it to understand what is happening. If there is something  that should concern me, what does it mean, and how can it be stopped?

```
[LAN access from remote] from 89.93.100.201:38730 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:08
[LAN access from remote] from 89.93.100.201:53842 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:08
[LAN access from remote] from 46.150.97.81:42668 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:05
[LAN access from remote] from 77.40.122.127:1025 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:04
[LAN access from remote] from 77.121.34.235:62155 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:04
[LAN access from remote] from 222.161.212.71:20406 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:03
[LAN access from remote] from 5.20.145.169:6881 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:43:02
[LAN access from remote] from 124.90.57.0:44539 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:59
[LAN access from remote] from 95.188.204.86:6899 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:59
[LAN access from remote] from 112.118.239.58:22695 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:58
[LAN access from remote] from 175.156.244.90:35416 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:58
[LAN access from remote] from 59.97.130.10:52048 to 192.168.1.2:11625, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:58
[UPnP set event: Public_UPNP_C3] from source 192.168.1.2, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:56
[Admin login] from source 192.168.1.2, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:37:36
```

**Part 2 the following is what occurred since I started this post**

I'm not sure if this means MAC address 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F gained access to my wireless router after many failed attempts at Oct 28, 2014 18:21:20. I looked at my router and saw it was connected but the device name was blank. Is this what it means and what could I do about it?

Here is the log

```
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.7)] to MAC address 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:48:04
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 74:E1:B6:68:BB:C3, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:41:16
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.7)] to MAC address 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:36:16
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.7)] to MAC address 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:21:20
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:21:04
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.8)] to MAC address BC:77:37:C8:55:A0, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:18:46
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [117.221.124.255], Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:18:05
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:17:29
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.9)] to MAC address 00:16:01:BC:6E:88, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:14:56
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 74:E1:B6:68:BB:C3, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:11:31
[Time synchronized with NTP server] Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:05:42
[Internet connected] IP address: 69.125.226.173, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 18:05:42
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.8)] to MAC address BC:77:37:C8:55:A0, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:59:42
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:52:10
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:51:05
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 74:E1:B6:68:BB:C3, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:46:01
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:22:10
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 70:DE:E2:1B:4F:3F, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:21:05
[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC 74:E1:B6:68:BB:C3, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:16:16
[DoS attack: Smurf] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [79.117.15.255], Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 17:13:39
```

Comment: You are getting all sorts of different traffic. Do you host a website or any servers? Anything that redirects to your external IP?

Comment: I do not host a website or server. I have a NAS device - Qnap that is suppose to be accesable from the Web but I do not think that functionality is turned on. I am concerned about all the traffic I am getting.

Comment: Once you’re online, you’re under attack. It’s as simple as that, and it’s the very same for everyone. It’s just that some consumer routers have *very* verbose logs.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up some of the geolocation of those IP addresses:

```
124.90.57.0   = Hangzhou,Zhejiang Sheng,China,Asia
89.93.100.201 = Marseille,Bouches-du-Rhône,Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur,France,Europe
46.150.97.81  = Donetsk,Donets'ka Oblast',Ukraine,Europe
```

Seems like you are getting pretty random traffic. If you have anything redirecting your outside traffic like a domain name then I suggest investigating that. IF you aren't hosting anything perhaps you can request your ISP change your IP address, regardless of dynamic or static.

If somebody was DDOS'ing you then they could be using proxies to make it seem like their IP is coming from Asia and Europe.

Comment: could something be running on my computers(virus?) that would causing this?

Comment: Well no since it is coming from an outside IP. I guess it could be a virus or something if it connects outside your network and then back in. First run a good virus check program. If nothing comes up either do as I suggested or try doing a fresh reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Is `192.168.1.2` one of your desktops?  Is it configured to be in as the 'DMZ'?  If so you are going to get lots of crap thrown at it.  This is normal.  When you set a host as the DMZ the router is basically going to forward all new incoming connections to that host.  If you use the DMZ setting in your router your host better have a properly configured host-based firewall.

You should also consider disabling UPNP, it allows devices on your network to open the firewall.

Comment: 192.168.1.2 is one of my computers. But in my router both  "Default DMZ Server" and "Turn UPnP On" are not checked. So I think that DMZ and UPNP are off.

Comment: The line `[UPnP set event: Public_UPNP_C3] from source 192.168.1.2, Tuesday, Oct 28,2014 07:42:56` leads me to think otherwise about uPnP.  Is there something actually listening on port 11625 on the computer at 192.168.1.2?  This looks kinda like incoming bitorrent connections to me.

Comment: I installed bitorrent yesterday and un-installed it after the entry in the log.